# I need to create a column based on overall pass/fail performance using Python

Tags: python, pandas, automation, data-analysis

| Asset | performance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pass |
| 1 | fail |
| 2 | pass |
| 3 | fail |
| 3 | fail |
| 4 | pass |

I have two columns. In column A are key values that may repeat, and in column B are individual instances of pass/fail. I need to create a column C using Pandas that returns "fail" if a particular asset contains a single failure.

| asset | performance | overall performance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pass | fail |
| 1 | fail | fail |
| 2 | pass | pass |
| 3 | fail | fail |
| 3 | fail | fail |
| 4 | pass | pass |

As seen here, an asset can both have a pass value and a fail value, however, if an asset's performance == fail, its overall performance must == fail. If an asset's performance only == pass, then it's overall performance should == pass. Is it possible to create a column in Python that tracks each instance of an asset's performance and returns "fail" for each row of that particular asset?

Comment: Do you have other states?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ordered `CategoricalDtype`:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['fail', 'pass'], ordered=True)
df['overall performance'] = (df.astype({'performance': cat})
                               .groupby('Asset')
                               .transform(min))
print(df)

# Output
   Asset performance overall performance
0      1        pass                fail
1      1        fail                fail
2      2        pass                pass
3      3        fail                fail
4      3        fail                fail
5      4        pass                pass
```

Or simply use the lexicographical order:

```
df['overall performance'] = (df.sort_values('performance')
                               .groupby('Asset')['performance']
                               .transform('first'))
print(df)

# Output
   Asset performance overall performance
0      1        pass                fail
1      1        fail                fail
2      2        pass                pass
3      3        fail                fail
4      3        fail                fail
5      4        pass                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

With *direct* transformation on `np.where` condition:

```
df['overall performance'] = df.groupby('Asset').transform(lambda x: np.where('fail' in x.values,'fail','pass'))
```

---

```
   Asset performance overall performance
0      1        pass                fail
1      1        fail                fail
2      2        pass                pass
3      3        fail                fail
4      3        fail                fail
5      4        pass                pass
```